# unknown column error even though clearly the same name column exists in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

When I run this query in in mysql

```
SELECT `projects.proj_id`,`title`,`man_id`,`desc` 
FROM `projects` , `assigned` 
WHERE projects.proj_id=assigned.proj_id  
AND assigned.user_id=1
```

It returns to me a

```
#1504 Unknown column 'projects.proj_id' in 'field list'
```

even when I have a clearly defined column called proj_id in the projects table. Am I missing out on something? I have been scratching my head for a while now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed some ` when enclosing .
Try this:

```
SELECT `projects`.`proj_id`,`title`,`man_id`,`desc` 
FROM `projects` , `assigned` 
WHERE projects.proj_id=assigned.proj_id  
AND assigned.user_id=1
```

Answer (score 3):

you have selected `projects.proj_id` as a column you should separet it 
try this

```
   SELECT projects.proj_id,title,man_id,`desc` 
   FROM projects , assigned 
   WHERE projects.proj_id=assigned.proj_id  
   AND assigned.user_id=1
```

or better use `JOIN`

```
      SELECT p.proj_id,title,man_id,`desc` 
      FROM projects p
      INNER JOIN  assigned a
      ON  p.proj_id=a.proj_id  
      WHERE assigned.user_id=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
SELECT projects.proj_id,title,man_id,desc 
FROM projects , assigned 
WHERE projects.proj_id=assigned.proj_id
AND assigned.user_id=1

Comment: Does the ` make a difference? I thought it was good practice to keep those.